# How can I customize this HTML Document Script to make it Loop?

Tags: javascript, html, loops, selenium

```html
<tr>
  <td>clickAt</td>
  <td>css=#Image_Scoreleft &gt; div.blockbody &gt; form &gt; input[type="submit"]
    <datalist>
      <option>css=#Image_Scoreleft &gt; div.blockbody &gt; form &gt; input[type="submit"]</option>       
      <option>//input[@value='Vote Up']</option>
      <option>//section[@id='Image_Scoreleft']/div/form/input[4]</option>
      <option>//input[4]</option>
    </datalist>
  </td>
  <td>202,8</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>clickAt</td>
  <td>css=#Image_Scoreleft &gt; div.blockbody &gt; form &gt; input[type="submit"]
    <datalist>
      <option>css=#Image_Scoreleft &gt; div.blockbody &gt; form &gt; input[type="submit"]</option>     
      <option>//input[@value='Vote Up']</option>
      <option>//section[@id='Image_Scoreleft']/div/form/input[4]</option>
      <option>//input[4]</option>
    </datalist>
  </td>
  <td>196,8</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>close</td>
  <td>win_ser_local
    <datalist>
      <option>win_ser_local</option>
    </datalist>
  </td>
  <td></td>
</tr>
```

So I am using SideeX to record my mouse clicks and I got it to work the way I want it to work however i want to improve this Script. How can I make it Loop running in the background?

Comment: 1. Do you wanna looped `<tr>` elements? 
2. On vannila JS?

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, SideeX is used for Selenium? It isn't clear where JavaScript comes into play here.